# Ryanair booking: adult marked as child, child marked as adult; problem?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, ryanair

On making ticket payment (ryanair.com online booking), where I need to enter passengers names, I made a mistake:

- In Child name field I put adult name
- In Adult name field I put a child name.

Child is 4 years old.

Could it make any problems, at checking or board in?

Answer (score 4):

It's **highly unlikely** that anybody will care: you're got the right names, the right number of seats and paid the correct fare.  At last check Ryanair boarding passes don't even distinguish between adult and child, unless it's a lap child (not the case here).  So odds are very high nobody will even notice, and in your shoes I would not do anything.

That said, Ryanair is famous for being bureaucratic and unreasonable, so there is a small but non-zero chance that you will encounter a pedantic ID checker who notices and raises a fuss.  The only way to avoid this would be to do a double name change, but that would cost a minimum of €35/flight/person.